# React useEffect not being triggered for default state

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks

When I try to set the page to the default value from refresh function, it doesn't trigger the useEffect hook. But if I run the refresh function 2nd time it works fine. And this code also works fine for other values like 2, 3, 4, 5......

```js
  const [goal, setGoal] = useState();
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [temp, setTemp] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setGoal();
    getData();
  }, [page]);

  const refresh = () => {
    setTemp([]);
    setPage(1);
  };
```

Comment: This is how react works, if you'd set the same value that state already has, react will not run re-rendering cycle. So clicking refresh second time, still having 1 as new value will never trigger useEffect. Are you really sure that when you click on you button second time it runs useEffect?

Comment: Can you please show how you call your refresh

Answer (score 1):

If page already has value "1" then refresh won't trigger useEffect, there must be some other value in "page" state to make     "setPage(1)" update it, and then if the state updates it will trigger useEffect.

Comment: Yeah, But if the current value of page is 10, still setPage(1) doesn't trigger useEffect

Comment: Alright, The code block looks fine though. If you put some more code reference then the problem could be identified.

Comment: There must be something wrong with how you call your refresh function then. I tried [this react playground](https://playcode.io/react), copy-pasted your code and added a button to trigger refresh. It never hits useEffect if you set the same value as the default one. Also it does execute useEffect if the default was 10, and you set it to 1 inside refresh. So very oposite to the behaviour you mentioned. How do you call your refresh function?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/33126577)

Comment: @DavidAnsermot I didn't get you. Can you please clarify what's wrong with the answer?

Answer (score 0):

For "refreshing" purposes it is actually a better idea to have separated state exactly for triggering re-rendering cycle in React

```
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)

const refresh = () => setCounter(counter + 1)
```

and then make your `useEffect` dependant on counter value

Answer (score 0):

**This is the easiest way to re-run the useEffect**

```
 const [refresh, setRefresh] = useState(false);

 useEffect(() => {
    setGoal();
    getData();
 }, [refresh]);

  //whenever you want to refresh just use this 
  setRefresh(!refresh)
```